# VueWarn TypeError: this.adPerformance.sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, sorting, typeerror

Hey I have a problem with my coding returning the above typeerror. I have a simple table I want to sort, with the following code.

```
<template>
<div>
<div class="row">
  <h2>Ad performance</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="socialAd">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Client</th>
          <th scope="col">Ad</th>
          <th scope="col">CPC</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(ad) in sortedAdPerformance" :key="ad.adID">
          <td>{{ad.client}}</td>
          <td @mouseover="mouseEnter(ad.previewURL)">{{ad.ad}}</td>
          <td>{{ad.CPC}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h4>Desktop preview</h4>
    <iframe
      :src="iframeURL"
      v-show="toShowOnHover"
      @mouseleave="mouseLeave"
      width="525"
      height="710"
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      toShowOnHover: false,
      iframeURL: null
    };
  },
  props: ["adPerformance"],
  components: {},
  methods: {
    mouseEnter: function(url) {
      this.toShowOnHover = true;
      this.iframeURL = url;
    },
    mouseLeave: function() {
      this.toShowOnHover = false;
      this.iframeURL = null;
    }
  },
computed: {
   sortedAdPerformance() {
      return this.adPerformance.sort((a, b) => b.CPC - a.CPC)
    }
  },
  created() {
  },
 };
</script>

<style>
 #socialAd{
 overflow-y:scroll;
 height: 700px;
 display:block;
 }
</style>
```

can anyone help me with this error? I have tried reading similar problems here, but I can't find a solution that works - I have also tried adding a watcher function, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use computed values like that if the prop 'adPerformance' is fetched from an api in parent component. You need to use watcher if this prop changes dynamically. If it doesnt change dynamically you can just sort it in mounted and save it to your data object For example:

```
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      toShowOnHover: false,
      iframeURL: null,
      sortedAdPerformance: []
    };
  },
  props: ["adPerformance"],
  components: {},
  methods: {
    mouseEnter: function(url) {
      this.toShowOnHover = true;
      this.iframeURL = url;
    },
    mouseLeave: function() {
      this.toShowOnHover = false;
      this.iframeURL = null;
    }
  },
//use watch only if your prop changes dynamically, if not then you do not need watcher.
  watch: {
   adPerformance: function() {
     this.sortedAdPerformance = this.adPerformance.sort((a, b) => b.CPC - a.CPC);
   }
  },
//use this hook only if prop changes dynamically
  updated() {
this.sortedAdPerformance = this.adPerformance.sort((a, b) => b.CPC - a.CPC);
  }
  mounted() {
    if(this.adPerformance){
     this.sortedAdPerformance=this.adPerformance.sort((a, b) => b.CPC - a.CPC);
}

  },
 };
</script>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response, just been away - So the prop changes dynamically, however I've tried added the watcher function. But now get the error of: [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "campaignPerformance"

Comment: There is no campaignPerformance in this piece of code which you provided but if it is in for loop try to use seperate component and use for loop for that component for example and you should put the logic to seperated component or emit functions to the parent.